# Google Python cloud-dataflow instances broke without new deployment (failed pubsub import)

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, requirements.txt

I have defined a few different Cloud Dataflow jobs for Python in the Google AppEngine Flex Environment. I have defined my requirements in a requirements.txt file, included my setup.py file, and everything was working just fine. My last deployment was on May 3rd, 2018. Looking through logs, I see that one of my jobs began failing on May 22nd, 2018. The job fails with a stack trace resulting from a bad import, seen below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
    op.start()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 294, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10607)
    def start(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 295, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10501)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 300, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:9702)
    pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 225, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_pipeline/tally_overages.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import PublisherClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import types
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/types.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.iam.v1.logging import audit_data_pb2
ImportError: No module named logging
```

So the main issue seems to come from the pubsub dependency relying on importing `google.iam.v1.logging`, which is installed from `grpc-google-iam-v1`.

Here is my requirements.txt file

```
Flask==0.12.2
apache-beam[gcp]==2.1.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-dataflow==2.1.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
pytz
google-cloud-pubsub
google-gax
grpc-google-iam-v1
googleapis-common-protos
google-cloud==0.32
six==1.10.0
protobuf
```

I am able to run everything locally just fine by doing the following from my project.

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages .
$ . bin/activate
$ pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
$ python main.py
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 317-820-645
```

specifically, I am able to do the following locally just fine

```
$ python
>>> from google.cloud import pubsub
>>> import google.iam.v1.logging
>>> google.iam.v1.logging.__file__
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/iam/v1/logging/__init__.pyc'
```

So I know that the installation of the `grpc-google-iam-v1` package is working just fine locally.. the required files are there.

My questions are

1. Why is the install of `grpc-google-iam-v1` on the Google AppEngine Flex Environment not installing all of the files correctly? I must be missing the `/site-packages/google/iam/v1/logging` directory.
2. Why would this randomly start failing? I didn't do any more deploys, the same code was running and working on the 21st and then it broke on the 22nd on May.

---

I was able to get the pipeline running again after changing the requirements.txt file to

```
Flask==0.12.2
apache-beam[gcp]
google-cloud-dataflow
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
pytz
google-cloud-pubsub
google-gax
grpc-google-iam-v1
googleapis-common-protos
google-cloud==0.32
six==1.10.0
protobuf
```

so simply removing the version requirements from `apache-beam[gcp]` and `google-cloud-dataflow` did the trick.

Comment: Would you mind posting that last edit as your own answer? For future reference of the community.

Comment: The docs say that you should just be using apache-beam SDK now, not google-cloud-dataflow anymore, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/installing-dataflow-sdk I think having both of those (especially without versions) in the requirements could be problematic. You should always specify versions in a production app. It's fine for libraries to use >= and the like in their dependencies, but for your production apps,  _Always pin your packages_ https://nvie.com/posts/pin-your-packages/

Comment: The Hitchiker's guide suggests to always created your requirements file using pip freeze: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solution provided by [John Allard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4652515/john-allard), [removing the version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) from the requirements.txt will automatically default to the latest version. Thus, with no version specified for `apache-beam[gcp]` , `google-cloud-dataflow` and `google-cloud-pubsub` they will all run on the latest version and solve the dependency issue. The requirements.txt will look like the following:

```
Flask==0.12.2
apache-beam[gcp]
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-dataflow
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
pytz
google-cloud-pubsub
google-gax
grpc-google-iam-v1
googleapis-common-protos
google-cloud==0.32
six==1.10.0
protobuf
```

Comment: this is happening again to me now. My jobs ran fine for over a month but last night they all started failing with a missing dependency. Why would stuff begin to break without any new deployments? The expectation is that, once code is deployed, it should run fine without having to worry about it randomly breaking due to changed you guys make to the back end. Example job-id: 2018-07-31_01_00_04-12578868961948807002

Comment: I think it is generally bad advice to remove versions from requirements of a production application. When you deploy something like this in a managed environment (like dataflow), you aren't necessarily doing a deployment that is final. Your code may be wrapped and containerized, and those container images could be rebuilt at any time at the whim of the managed service provider for something upstream in e.g. a dockerfile. Even if you were deploying to a VM, in between your testing on a local build and deploying there could be a new version of one package that breaks the build on production.