# Can no longer install `google-cloud-datastore` dependency for Google Cloud Dataflow jobs in requirements.txt file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, python-import, google-cloud-dataflow

Something similar to this last post happened again: [Google Python cloud-dataflow instances broke without new deployment (failed pubsub import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729803/google-python-cloud-dataflow-instances-broke-without-new-deployment-failed-pubs)

Essentially, overnight, all of our cloud dataflow jobs broke for seemingly no reason. There were no new deployments, there were no SDK updates, nothin, our team simply awoke to StackDriver notifications saying that our mapping jobs failed overnight.

This is the stack trace that the jobs are failing with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 609, in do_work work_executor.execute()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute op.start()
    File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 340, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start def start(self):
    File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 341, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start with self.scoped_start_state:
    File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 346, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 225, in loads return dill.loads(s)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads return load(file)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load obj = pik.load()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load dispatch[key](self)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global klass = self.find_class(module, name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class __import__(module)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_pipeline/invoice_overages.py", line 26,
in <module> from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf ImportError: No module named datastore.helpers
```

I've tried to reproduce the error locally and it seems that this comes from an inability to install `google-cloud-datastore`.

This is our current `requirements.txt` file contents

```
Flask==0.12.2
apache-beam[gcp]
google-cloud-dataflow
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
pytz
google-cloud-pubsub
google-gax
grpc-google-iam-v1
googleapis-common-protos
google-cloud==0.32
six==1.10.0
protobuf
```

I'm currently mostly unable to reproduce this locally. I install these requirements

```
httplib2==0.9.1
oauth2client==3.0.0
google-cloud-dataflow==2.5.0
```

and I get the error that is shown above,

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    import dataflow_pipeline.summarize_intervals as summarization_pipeline
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/dataflow_pipeline/summarize_intervals.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf
ImportError: No module named datastore.helpers
(venv)
```

but if I then do `pip install --ignore-installed google-cloud-datastore`

I get this crazy error

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    import dataflow_pipeline.summarize_intervals as summarization_pipeline
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/dataflow_pipeline/summarize_intervals.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1 import types
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/types.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/datastore_pb2.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import entity_pb2 as google_dot_cloud_dot_datastore__v1_dot_proto_dot_entity__pb2
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity_pb2.py", line 28, in <module>
    dependencies=[google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_struct__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_timestamp__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_type_dot_latlng__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
  File "/Users/john/camio-mappers/box-counters-pipeline/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 878, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto":
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.project_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.namespace_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId.namespace_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.PartitionId: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id: "google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.path: "google.datastore.v1.Key.path" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id_type: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id_type" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.kind: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.kind" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.name: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement.name" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key: "google.datastore.v1.Key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.value_type: "google.datastore.v1.Value.value_type" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.null_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.null_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.boolean_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.boolean_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.integer_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.integer_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.double_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.double_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.timestamp_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.timestamp_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.string_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.string_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.blob_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.blob_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.geo_point_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.geo_point_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value: "google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.meaning: "google.datastore.v1.Value.meaning" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value.exclude_from_indexes: "google.datastore.v1.Value.exclude_from_indexes" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Value: "google.datastore.v1.Value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.key: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.key: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Entity: "google.datastore.v1.Entity" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto".
  google.datastore.v1.Key.partition_id: "google.datastore.v1.PartitionId" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Key.path: "google.datastore.v1.Key.PathElement" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue.values: "google.datastore.v1.Value" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.key_value: "google.datastore.v1.Key" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.entity_value: "google.datastore.v1.Entity" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Value.array_value: "google.datastore.v1.ArrayValue" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry.value: "google.datastore.v1.Value" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.key: "google.datastore.v1.Key" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.datastore.v1.Entity.properties: "google.datastore.v1.Entity.PropertiesEntry" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/datastore/v1/entity.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

I have no idea what any of this means. I do seem to be missing the listed `.proto` files, but why would they be missing?

My main question is this, as it was the last time this happened: why is it okay for jobs to break when we aren't doing any new deployments? The assumption is that, if we don't change any code, the code shouldn't break. If we don't change any dependencies, we shouldn't end up with broken pipelines that we then have to scramble to fix. Cloud Dataflow is out of beta and should be stable, if it was in beta and subject to API changes this would be expected, but it should be stable at this point. As of now our pipelines are down and we don't know how long for.

---

I made the suggested change to `google-cloud-datastore==1.4.0` and it partly fixed my pipeline, but now it is failing at another point. It appears that `google-cloud-pubsub` is now failing with a similar error of missing `.proto` files

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
    import dataflow_pipeline.tally_overages as overaging_pipeline
  File "/home/vmagent/app/dataflow_pipeline/tally_overages.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import PublisherClient
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import types
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/types.py", line 30, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.proto import pubsub_pb2
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub_pb2.py", line 29, in <module>
    dependencies=[google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_duration__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_empty__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_field__mask__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_timestamp__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 878, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto":
  google.pubsub.v1.Topic.name: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic.name" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Topic: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.data: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.data" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.attributes: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.attributes" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.message_id: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.message_id" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.publish_time: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.publish_time" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry.key: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry.key" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry.value: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry.value" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage.AttributesEntry" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage: "google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.GetTopicRequest.topic: "google.pubsub.v1.GetTopicRequest.topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.GetTopicRequest: "google.pubsub.v1.GetTopicRequest" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest.topic: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest.topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest.messages: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest.messages" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PublishResponse.message_ids: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishResponse.message_ids" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.PublishResponse: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishResponse" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.project: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.project" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.page_size: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.page_size" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.page_token: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest.page_token" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse.topics: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse.topics" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse.next_page_token: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse.next_page_token" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.topic: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.page_size: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.page_size" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.page_token: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest.page_token" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse.subscriptions: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse.subscriptions" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse.next_page_token: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse.next_page_token" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.DeleteTopicRequest.topic: "google.pubsub.v1.DeleteTopicRequest.topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.DeleteTopicRequest: "google.pubsub.v1.DeleteTopicRequest" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.name: "google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.name" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.topic: "google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.topic" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.push_config: "google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.push_config" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.ack_deadline_seconds: "google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.ack_deadline_seconds" is already defined in file "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto".
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.retain_acked_messages: "google.pubsub.v1.Subscription.retain_acked_messages" is already defined in 
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Seek: "google.pubsub.v1.SeekRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.Seek: "google.pubsub.v1.SeekResponse" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.CreateTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.CreateTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.UpdateTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.Publish: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.Publish: "google.pubsub.v1.PublishResponse" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.GetTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.GetTopicRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.GetTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.Topic" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.ListTopics: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.ListTopics: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicsResponse" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.ListTopicSubscriptions: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.ListTopicSubscriptions: "google.pubsub.v1.ListTopicSubscriptionsResponse" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.DeleteTopic: "google.pubsub.v1.DeleteTopicRequest" seems to be defined in "google/cloud/proto/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto", which is not imported by "google/cloud/pubsub_v1/proto/pubsub.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

I don't really understand what these errors mean. This is my new requirements.txt file

```
httplib2==0.9.1
oauth2client==3.0.0
google-cloud-dataflow==2.5.0
dill==0.2.6
Flask
gunicorn
pytz
googledatastore
google-cloud-datastore==1.4.0
google-cloud
google-cloud-pubsub
```

edit - here are the import lines of code

file 1

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# standard imports
import datetime
import json
import logging
import base64
import collections
import traceback
import hashlib
from functools import reduce

# apache beam / dataflow imports
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# google cloud datastore imports
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper, PropertyFilter, CompositeFilter
from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf

# custom utility imports
from .util import *
```

file 2

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import datetime
import math
import json
import logging
import traceback
import collections
import hashlib
from functools import reduce

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper, PropertyFilter, CompositeFilter
from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf
from google.cloud import pubsub

from .util import *
```

file 3

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import math
import json
import logging
import traceback
import uuid
import collections
import hashlib
import datetime
from functools import reduce

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper, PropertyFilter, CompositeFilter
from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf
from google.cloud import pubsub

from .util import *
```

and from the `util.*` files

```
import re
import os
import math
import datetime
import json
import logging
import base64
import traceback
import itertools
import pytz
import requests
from functools import reduce

# google cloud datastore imports
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper, PropertyFilter, CompositeFilter
from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf
```

Comment: I tried this `from google.cloud.datastore.helpers import entity_from_protobuf`, it works smoothly for me. The only difference between us is my google-cloud-datastore version is 1.4.0, may be try to update?

Comment: I have since removed the version of google-cloud-datastore and the problem still persists. I will try specifying version 1.4.0

Comment: The thing that I really want to know is why these things break without us having done anything. We would assume that when we get a working build out into production that it will run in a stable fashion until any of the underlying SDKs/APIs are deprecated and that that would only happen on a reasonable schedule. Waking up to all of our batch jobs failing due to some import error after no change of our own is unacceptable for a production pipeline.

Comment: You should complain about this on github, I think. Besides, as I try to reproduce your error but seems like other problem occurs. If anyone interested can enter https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177141/gcp-problem-51623806 for discussion, rather than expanding the comment list.

Comment: I'm attempting to reproduce the issue. Please can you provide the import lines your script is using?

Comment: @ChristopherP I added the import code to the original post, at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting it working by making a minimal collection of pipelines and adding the dependencies one by one until I found some combination that worked. The dependencies are as follows

```
Flask
gunicorn
apache-beam[gcp]==2.6.0
oauth2client==3.0.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.28.0
google-cloud-core==0.27.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
```

still quite frustrated that this stuff breaks with no warning and no action on our side, our production pipelines were taken offline for a week,  but it's up now and hopefully this will help someone out there.

EDIT -

Spoke too soon. This combination works locally but still breaks in the cloud >:-(

EDIT2 -

so.. it seems that Google stopped installing from `requirements.txt` file. I had this in my `setup.py` file

`REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['google-cloud']`

and it looks like that was the only dependency being installed! When I added this code

```
if os.path.exists('requirements.txt'):
    with open('requirements.txt') as fh:
        REQUIRED_PACKAGES=[line.strip() for line in fh.readlines()]
```

it all worked! now my pipeline runs.

So it looks like Google changed something where they stopped installing from `requirements.txt`.

WHAT!?!

Comment: I would like to point as well to the 3rd point on PyPI Dependencies from the [beam.apache documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/):
  3.- Run your pipeline with the following command-line option:   

**--requirements_file requirements.txt**

Comment: I don't think Google changed anything: [Python runtime will automatically install all dependencies declared in your requirements.txt during deployment **only in Google Cloud App Engine**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries)

Comment: @Temu I'm a bit confused.. the second link you sent states that it will install the requirements.txt dependencies while running in the GAE Flex Environment, but that's exactly what this issue is all about, it's no longer doing just that. If I deploy to the flex environment, the requirements are not installed unless enumerated in the setup.py file.

Comment: @Temu also, as to your first point, I don't give the command-line options when the pipeline is running in the cloud, I simply state the entry point to the pipeline `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app` and let her rip?

Comment: @Temu, or, do you mean that I should set the `requirements_file` value inside of the `beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)` dictionary? I guess that leaves the question of why this was working before but then randomly stopped working? The link that you sent already states that GAE Flex environment installs from requirements.txt file so isn't this a redundant step meant for local development?

Comment: In the github repo, you can see the code Google uses to turn your Python app into a dockerfile. If it finds a `requirements.txt` file in your source, then the contents of the following file is appended to the dockerfile, which results in those requirements being installed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime/blob/master/scripts/data/Dockerfile.requirements_txt I don't see any recent commits that would have broken that behaviour. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime/blob/7eb071f7f7526815fc4b90a5ed0225f1247eef84/scripts/gen_dockerfile.py#L197

Comment: The only specification is that the `requirements.txt` file is in your `source_dir` which I guess is the same directory as app.yml
There's some good example projects here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python